# How to get all of view fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to display a popupwindow in the center of my Fragments, Also need a method for get view of fragment for example `getview()` to return all the view of  my activity .i need a method same getview but return view of my fragment not activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getview();` method will return the view of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_id);
```

or:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.id_of_view);
```

---

```
Open for correction, as always!

Regards,
Edward Quixote.
```